# Extract information in a span over multiple HTML documents

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, extract

I have a problem in which I have around 700 html documents, each containing one letter contained in a span, all in given the same class.

is there a way to get out all the letters and join them together? Maybe using BeautifulSoup or other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is. Try something like this:

```
import os
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

letter_list = []
for file in os.listdir('path/to/dir'):
    with open('path/to/file', 'r') as html_file:
        html = ' '.join(str(x) for x in list(html_file)) # Combines each row in file into a single string
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

        letter = soup('span',{'class':'someclass'})[0].contents[0]
        letter_list.append(letter)

my_string = ''.join(str(x) for x in letter_list)
```

This will iterate over the directory, open each html file and parse the string. The extracted letter is appended to a list and joined once all of the files have been parsed.